# Sum of values from rows if criteria found in horizontal range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet with a number of row records containing `country/value` pairs (**A2:C11**) and row records representing `regions` listing those `countries` horizontally (**14:16**):

[image]

What I would like to do is to sum up all the country values for each region:

[image]

Conceptually I know what I need to do, for instance for North America (**B19**):

- filter **B2:B11** range where **B** found in row **14**
- sum up values from **C2:11** corresponding to filtered **B2:B11** range

Which in this case would give `10 (C2) + 11 (C5) + 12 (C10) = 33`

I believe the functions I need are the [lookup and reference functions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/excel-functions-by-category-HP005204211.aspx#_Toc260837859), but I just have no idea as to where to start:

**Can someone give me an example for B19 (or at least list of functions I should be using)?**

*PS: I don't want to use VBA, just formulas*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this formula in `B19` copied down

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(B$2:B$11,INDEX(B$14:C$16,MATCH(A19,A$14:A$16,0),0),C$2:C$11))`

- `MATCH` gives you the correct row in table two
- then `INDEX` gives you all countries in that row.
- The `INDEX/MATCH` part then forms the criteria argument for `SUMIF`, and because the criteria is a range of values `SUMIF` returns an array (the sum for each country separately)......so `SUMPRODUCT` is used to sum the array, avoiding "array entry"

Comment: It worked on `B19` but I had to replace `MATCH(A$19` with `MATCH($A19` to copy it down to `B20` and `B21`.

Comment: Sorry, yes - that $ shouldn't have been included........now corrected....

Comment: AFAIK there isn't an equivalent to `SUMPRODUCT` for counting, am I right?

Comment: If you just want a count replace SUMIF with COUNTIF, SUMPRODUCT would remain, so `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(B$2:B$11,INDEX(B$14:C$16,MATCH(A19,A$14:A$16,0),0)))`

Comment: You're the best ;)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, since there's more than 1 country per region, you'll need a rather lengthy formula. I'm suggesting using both `SUMIF()` and `VLOOKUP()`.

```
=SUMIF($B$2:$B$11,VLOOKUP(A19,$A$14:$C$16,2,FALSE),$C$2:$C$11)+
 SUMIF($B$2:$B$11,VLOOKUP(A19,$A$14:$C$16,3,FALSE),$C$2:$C$11)
```

The first `SUMIF()` is calculating the sum for Canada only, and the second for US only. Adding the two gives the sum for the region.

`VLOOKUP()` retrieves the country name from the region name, you'll notice the different is in the `VLOOKUP()`, where the first is `2` and the second is `3` (just before false). You can of course replace `FALSE` by `0` to output the same results.

---

Also, if you want a shorter, but an array formula, this one works as well:

```
=SUM(SUMIF($B$2:$B$11,IF(A19=$A$14:$A$16,$B$14:$C$16),$C$2:$C$11))
```

Since this is an array formula however, you'll have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: First formula works, but not the second.

Comment: @user359650 You have to press Ctrl, Shift AND Enter at the same time for it to work instead of simply Enter here as it is an array formula :)

Comment: What I like with your solution is that I can easily replace `SUMIF` with `COUNTIF` if I want to count, whereas with `Barry`'s solution I don't have an equivalent for `SUMPRODUCT`

Comment: +1 for the array formula - that would definitely be the way to go where you have multiple matches for the region.......

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$2:$C$11,--(IFERROR(MATCH($B$2:$B$11,$B14:$C14,0),0)<>0))
```

at cell B19 and drag it down. If you have more than 2 countries per region, you need to extend the `$B14:$C14` accordingly.

Note: this is an array formula, so you copy it to the cell and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to make it work.

- `IFERROR(MATCH(...,0))` returns an array whose elements show the position of each entry of the first table, in the appropriate row of the second table.
- The logical condition converts all zeros to `FALSE` and all other numbers to `TRUE`
- The `--` part converts the `TRUE` and `FALSE` values to `1` and `0` respectively
- `SUMPRODUCT` operates on two arrays: the first is the original range, and the second is a `0/1` array that encompasses the conditions we entered before.

Here is a nice post that explains the logic behind such formulas:
http://www.excelhero.com/blog/2010/01/the-venerable-sumproduct.html

Comment: This works without referencing the region so it requires regions in tables 2 and 3 to be listed in the same order - you could simplify to this version if that was the case `=SUMPRODUCT(C$2:C$11*(B$2:B$11=B14:C14))`

Comment: @barryhoudini Yes, I assumed that there is no need to check that tables are in same order. The above method is still nice (and your version much more condensed), but I would still go with your original answer as it avoids array formulas.

Comment: @barryhoudini Just checked `=SUM(C$2:C$11*(B$2:B$11=B14:C14))`  (instead of `SUMPRODUCT` as above). It still works, since finally there is only one array (the Cartesian product of the conditions). Nice!

Comment: Yes, SUM is good too, I only suggest SUMPRODUCT because it doesn't need to be "array entered" as it would with SUM

Comment: @barryhoudini  V Good point  - Thanks!