# SUMIF/INDEX/MATCH formula not giving correct totals

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a large spreadsheet of business counts across hundreds of small regions (see [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNprB.png)). I have used the following formula to try and identify all rows with the relevant name (e.g. Abbotsford) and sum the total business column:

```
=SUMIF($C$3:$C$46022,F4,INDEX($D$3:$D$46022,MATCH(F4,$C$3:$C$46022,0),0))
```

Unfortunately, while the total for the first region is correct, the remaining regions either significantly undercount the actual total or return the value 0.

I attempted the following alternative formula (per this [solution](https://superuser.com/questions/614151/sum-of-values-from-rows-if-criteria-found-in-horizontal-range)), but it also does not return the correct total:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(C$3:C$46022,INDEX(F$4:F$24,MATCH(F5,F5,0),0),D$3:D$46022))
```

Comment: What is the reason you have added INDEX MATCH in your SUMIF? Have you tried =SUMIF($C$3:$C$46022,F4,$D$3:$D$46022)

Comment: Inexperience essentially! I just tried your alternative formula and it works perfectly - thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [pat2015](https://superuser.com/users/453732/pat2015) for providing a solution that solved this problem. It appears that there is no need to have INDEX or MATCH in the formula:

```
=SUMIF($C$3:$C$46022,F4,$D$3:$D$46022)
```

It also appears that SUMPRODUCT can provide a correct response, as per the following formula that provided on [this website](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($C$3:$C$46022=F4),$D$3:$D$46022)
```